# For vectors $0 \neq s,y \in \mathbb{R^n}$ with $(s,y)>0$ there exist only one positive definite symmetric matrix $Q$ such that $Qs = y$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

The statement above was given as an exercise to prove. I've done the existence part. The problem with it is that the part about uniqueness might be a typo. Is it unique?

Comment: Is there not a confusion between $y$ and $v$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net yes thanks! Corrected the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clearly not true.

Take $s=y=e_1$ where $e_1$ is the first vector of the canonical basis then any diagonal matrix $Q$ with for diagonal $1, \lambda_2, \dots , \lambda_n$ where $\lambda_i \gt 0$ is symmetric positive definite and such that $Qs=y$.

Comment: This is just nitpicky, but don't $s$ and $v$ have to be strictly positive vectors?

Comment: @paulinho I don’t know what means to be positive for vectors??? Can you elaborate ? At least the inner product $(e_1,e_1)$ is strictly positive, which is what is requested in the question.

Comment: @paulinho no, only strictly positive inner product, but thanks for your counterexample also

Comment: Ah, I see. I wasn't aware that the notation $( \cdot, \cdot)$ referred to the inner product here. I took it to mean that each element of $s$ and $y$ were positive

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not unique. Consider
$$s = y = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$
Then there are infinitely many positive semi-definite matrices $Q$ that have $s$ as a $1$-eigenvector, namely $Q s = s = y$. To construct these examples, just consider an eigendecomposition of a positive definite $Q$ which has $s$ as a $1$-eigenvector. Then the eigendecomposition is of the form
$S D S^\dagger$
where $s / \|s\|$ is a column of $S$ (which is unitary), the corresponding diagonal entry in $D$ is one, and the rest of the diagonal entries in $D$ are also positive. For example,
$$\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \right) \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \mu \end{bmatrix} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}\right)$$
satisfies the criterion for any positive $\mu$.